# Ambiguous handler methods in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2, path-variables

I have these two `GetMapping` method in my *Spring Boot* application :

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
User one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
}



@GetMapping("/user/{uid}")
User one(@PathVariable String uid) {
    return repository.findByDisplayName(uid);
            //.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
}
```

I want to `GetMapping` by `userID`(auto-generated) or `uniqueUserID`(a `String` created by the user if available).

But this gives me error, saying :

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/user/dis1': {com.mua.cse616.Model.User com.mua.cse616.Controller.UserController.one(java.lang.Long), com.mua.cse616.Model.User com.mua.cse616.Controller.UserController.one(java.lang.String)}*

How this can be resolved ?

Comment: The mapping is exactly the same, it doesn't know the type when parsing the expression at startup. You can try limiting the first one (numeric) by using an additional regexp after the `id` part. Try `@GetMapping("/user/{id:\\d+}")`, however this assumes that a `uid` always contains a non-numeric character, else the matching won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set another name to one of your mappings.
When your controller receives `/user/1234`, it can't guess if `1234` must be parsed as a String or a Long and so it cannot choose which method has to be called.
That's the reason why the same pattern cannot be reused for different GET methods. If you had a `PostMapping` and a `GetMapping`, you could reuse the pattern, but in your case,  it's not the cleanest solution.

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
User one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
}


// Mapping changed to handle calls like /user/uid/2345-ABCD-5678
@GetMapping("/user/uid/{uid}")
User one(@PathVariable String uid) {
    return repository.findByDisplayName(uid);
            //.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, I'm just accepting `String`, then parsing , validating, this is how I'm trying to do my job. BTW, thanks a lot for helping.